# Could you please add the `pine` language code to three tags?

Tags: feature-request, tags, syntax-highlighting

I would like to implement highlighting for [Pine Script™](https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-docs/en/v5/Introduction.html) code, which is typically used in the following tags:

- [pine-script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/pine-script)
- [pine-script-v4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/pine-script-v4)
- [pine-script-v5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/pine-script-v5)

Could you please associate the `pine` language code to those three tags? The language is already supported in `highlight.js` and devs will maintain support for it as needed.

Comment: TradingView is generic charting software. Has nothing to do with crypto per se, except if you consider that a small proportion of the 600K data feeds we provide are in the crypto sector, which in no way means TV endorses the instruments, just as we do not endorse those of the more conventional sectors for which many more feeds are available.

Comment: Yeah, I deleted my comments once I looked this up, but I think it's useful that your comment remains, for clarification to others popping by.

Comment: This has been up before (or something similar related to Pine Script). Where are those MSO posts?

Comment: I mistakenly posted a [related question on MSE today](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/388320/can-we-have-the-pine-language-code-associated-with-specific-tags-in-order-to-h) and was redirected here, but afaik it's the first time such a request is made on MSO.

Comment: pine needs to be [in this list](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/184108/what-is-syntax-highlighting-and-how-does-it-work/184109#184109) so at the moment your request is not possible. You'd need to persuade Stack Exchange developers to support it and for that you'd probably need to supply some numbers about what percentage of Stack Overflow uses pine.

Comment: I'm sorry that you were directed here without more guidance. The users on MSE who told you to make this request here must have missed that this is not a supported language. Moderators can *only* set tag highlighting for languages that are supported by Stack Exchange's limited *subset* of Highlight.js languages. The network-wide deployment of a new language is a slightly different request and covered in the ["Requesting that Stack Exchange support a new language which is already supported by highlight.js" section](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/184109).

Comment: The language is already supported by highlight JS, so it would be quite easy for SE devs to enable it. I understand that moderators may not be able to do this but that doesn't mean the question should be closed

Comment: The duplicate is outdated, the process of requesting an existing language in highlight.js to be supported by Stack Exhange's fork is to raise a request on the übermeta.

Comment: Thank you all for your enlightening comments. I will go back to MSE.